# How do you tell Android Studio 3.0 where to find external ndk source files?

Tags: makefile, android-ndk, android-studio-3.0

We have an ndk build that, as part of the build (in an add_custom_command in a trivial CMakeLists.txt file) runs a gnu make.  When we build in Android Studio 3.0, the error messages for the build are partially processed, so they show up in the error pane as actual errors, but double-clicking on them does nothing.

How do we tell Android Studio 3.0 where to find the source files referenced by these builds?  (There is less-than-zero chance that we're going to do the work required to convert them to cmake.  They're not at all small, and they involve many third-party projects that each have their own custom build systems.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of a hack, but it resolves the major problem. Add a dummy static library to your **CMakeLists.txt**, e.g.

```
FILE(GLOB_RECURSE
    DUMMY1_SOURCES
    /path/to/third-party/project/*.cpp)

add_library( dummy1 STATIC ${DUMMY1_SOURCES})
```

**CMake** will ignore this static library during build, because the primary target does not depend on it, but the files will appear in **ANdroid** view under the **cpp** node.

> the error messages for the build are partially processed, so they show up in the error pane as actual errors, but double-clicking on them does nothing.

This is strange, I could add a message of format

```
message (ERROR "
    /home/alex/test/jni/Android.mk:10")
```

Even though the file does not belong to the project, and is not C++, it still shows as a clickable link in my Gradle console, and in the Messages window.

Comment: +1, although it doesn't actually solve the problem.  It does add symbols in the file to Android Studio (so you can use things like navigate to symbol), but it doesn't hook up errors so you can click on the error and jump to source.

Comment: Interestingly, though, you do get red squigglies in the file, so it's definitely worth doing.  Start small though - trying to bulk add every *.c file in our system never even finished importing; I ended up just bringing in the files for the particular section I'm working on.

Comment: re: but double-clicking on error messages - see update